# R split vector with jumps

Tags: r, vector, split

I have vector created with the following structure:

```
full_seq <- runif(10^8)
```

I want to generate a new vector, extracting samples of the same size. This works fine for me:

```
full_splited <- split(full_seq, ceiling(seq_along(full_seq)/10^3))
```

Now, I need to jump from one to another chunk by a fixed size. Lets take a sequence of 100 numbers, samples of 10 elements and a jump of 4 elements to ilustrate:

```
full_seq = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 .. 100
full_splitted2 [1] = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
               [2] = 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 
               [3] = 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 
               [4] = 40 .. 49 
               [5] = 53 .. 62 
               [6] = 66 .. 75
               [7] = 79 .. 88
```

The 8th element of **full_splited2** is outside of boundaries of **full_seq** and don't became a member of the splited object.

I don't know if that is the better representation but I've tried some solutions without success.

Any help?

A lot of thanks.

Comment: What is `full_along`?

Comment: If you reduce the sample (10^8 doesn't seem minimal) you can provide the desired output for your example which will make it easier to help. Also note that you should use `set.seed(somenumber)` when using random number generation/sampling to make it reproducible.

Comment: If I understand properly your question, intuitively I would reshape your vector into a matrix (with `ncol` being equal to the desired size of your samples) and then select the appropriate lines for example, but I don't understand what is `full_along` and exactly what you want, so...

Comment: @ztl Sorry, it was typping mistake seq_along is the right ...

Comment: @docendodiscimus Ok, I understand the principles of Random number Generation, I just reproduce here the portion that is my problem. Split the sequence in n subsequences of same size and jumping from one to another by a fixed number of elements. ie: 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
full_seq <- 1:100 
mysize <- 10
myjump <- 4

myseq <- seq(from=1, to=length(full_seq), by=myjump+mysize-1)
full_splitted2 <- c()
for (i in myseq) {
  if ((i+mysize-1) <= length(full_seq)) {
    full_splitted2 <- c(full_splitted2, full_seq[i:(i+mysize-1)])
  }
}
full_splitted2 <- matrix(full_splitted2, ncol=mysize, byrow=TRUE)
```

`full_splitted2`:

```
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
[2,]   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22    23
[3,]   27   28   29   30   31   32   33   34   35    36
[4,]   40   41   42   43   44   45   46   47   48    49
[5,]   53   54   55   56   57   58   59   60   61    62
[6,]   66   67   68   69   70   71   72   73   74    75
[7,]   79   80   81   82   83   84   85   86   87    88
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't made myself so clear. Let me try to explain again. SInce I have a full_seq = 10^2, myze = 10 and myjump = 3. The goal is a sequence like that: `full_seq = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 .. 100 full_splitted2 [1] = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 [2] = 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 [3] = 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 [4] = 40 .. 49 [5] = 53 .. 62 [6] = 66 .. 75 [7] = 79 .. 88` the 8th element is out of boundaries of full_splitted2 Got it?

Comment: Thanks, your question is really clearer now ;-) Answer adapted - hope it helps (likely to be improved...)

Comment: Thank YOU @ztl. You don't mind how it helps me! Really thanks.